# How to comprare List items between itselves and remove the oldest

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a given dummy List with the content:

```
index: 0; id:5; content:"foo"; <- oldest
index: 1; id:2; content:"bar"; <- oldest
index: 2; id:5; content: "foobar" <- new entry
```

I would like to interate over the list comparing the entries, when it found a matching id it removes the oldest entry from the List.

I tried Java 8 distinct() method but it removes the last entry not the oldest remaining the two oldests.

Comment: And how do you know which is the oldest?

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` seems to do exactly this.

Comment: You can remove the *first* entry in the list, but there's no way for the `List` to know which is the *oldest*.

Comment: If they are entered in order, when you find a match, remove the one with the lowest index

Comment: @meskobalazs the previous one with the same `id` (found a matching id it removes the oldest).

Comment: Does it have to be a `List`? If not, I would use what @biziclop suggested

Comment: I can change the types, I'll try to se the `LinkedHashMap` @biziclop @Ascalonian

Answer (score 0):

Algo:-

1)Sort the list making List of Generic type for e.g

```
List<YourPOJO> temp = new ArrayList<YourPOJO>();
```

YourPOJO class will have all the variables you have mentioned as class variables with setter getter methods.

2) sort the list by implementing comparator interface on your YourPOJO class on index variable.

3) now for performing operation first copy data into a list of CopyOnArrayList of same type and then remove the element.

4) Why CopyOnArrayList ?? because traversing same list and removing element from same list will throw Concurrent modification exception, even if you iterate through Iterator because Iterators are practically not thread safe.